# Protractor Basic Error Message E2E

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor, angular6

Just started learning angular and am now focusing on automated testing. I have a very simple app that consists of a basic form that asks the user to enter their email. I have a validators.required attached to the email so the user must enter some text. If the user does not enter any text, a message appears under the input field stating that the form is required. I am trying to test in Protractor that this message appears but am running into an error. I think it is just something very simple wrong with my code. I am using the latest revision of angular and Jasmine. Thank you. Any guidance would be great as I am having trouble finding good resources when using Angular2+.

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="!email; else forminfo">
  <form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="submitEmail(rForm.value)">
    <div class="form-container">
      <div class="row columns">

        <h1>{{title}}</h1>

        <label>Email
          <input type="text" formControlName="email">
        </label>
        <div class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['email'].valid && rForm.controls['email'].touched">{{ titleAlert }}</div>
         <input type="submit" class="button expanded" value="Submit Form" [disabled]="!rForm.valid">

         <button (click)="clickBtn()">test</button>
         <br>
         <p>{{msg}}</p>


      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<ng-template #forminfo>
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="row columns">
      <h1>Thank you for subscribing!</h1>

        <p>Email you have subscribed with: {{ email }}</p> <br> 

    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Component Class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Enter email to subscribe';
  private location: Location;
  rForm: FormGroup;
  submit: any;
  email:string = '';
  titleAlert:string = 'This field is required';
  titleEmail:string = "Email required";
  titleLength: string = 'Min of 7 Characters'
  msg: string;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.rForm = fb.group( {
      'email': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(7),Validators.email]]
    })
  }

  points = 1;



  ngOnInit() {

  }

  clickBtn() {
    this.msg = 'test'
  }

  submitEmail(submit) {
    this.email = submit.email;
  }
}
```

Object Class

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/');
  }

  getTitle() {
    return element(by.css('h1')).getText();
  }

  getTestBtn() {
    return element(by.cssContainingText('button', 'test'));
  }
  getErrorMsg() {
    return element(by.cssContainingText('div', 'alert')).getText();

  }

  getInputField() {
    return element(by.cssContainingText('input', 'email'));
  }



}
```

Spec Class

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';

describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();

  });

  it('Should display the correct title', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getTitle()).toEqual('Enter email to subscribe')
  });

  it('should display an input field', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getInputField()).toBeTruthy();
  })

  it('return an error if text box is left empty', () => {
    page.navigateTo();

    page.getInputField().sendKeys('');
    page.getTestBtn().click();

    expect(page.getErrorMsg()).toBeTruthy();

  })
});
```

Edit: Got it working by doing this:

```
   Object Class

  titleAlert = element(by.className('alert');
}
Spec Class

     expect(page.titleAlert.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Thank you tehbeardedone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
getErrorMsg() {
  return element(by.cssContainingText('div', 'alert')).getText();
}
```

In your component you have set the text of the error message to:

```
titleAlert: string = 'This field is required';
```

You should be looking for the element containing that text. Not for one containing `alert`. Or better yet, just use `by.className('alert')`

A better option would be to verify the error message is actually displayed when you try to submit an invalid form.

Ways to locate the element:

```
export class AppPage {
  titleAlert = element(by.className('alert'));

  // or ...

  titleAlert = element(by.cssContainingText('div', 'This field is required'));
}
```

Then in your test you can just do this:

```
it('return an error if text box is left empty', () => {
  page.navigateTo();

  page.getInputField().sendKeys('');
  page.getTestBtn().click();

  expect(page.titleAlert.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
});
```

Also, you may want to take a look at the [protractor style guide](https://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide). Specifically the section on page objects. You are currently heading down a path of adding unnecessary complexity to your tests. What I mean is stuff like `page.getInputField().sendKeys('');` is unnecessary when you can just do `page.myInputElement.sendKeys()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it immensely. Do you recommend any good resources for front end testing in protractor? Once again, thank you!